# Formar correctamente un json para realizar una petición

Tags: c#, json

Estoy intentando realizar una solicitud `POST` a un recurso web, sin embargo no puedo lograr establecer el formato del cuerpo correcto de el json que pide este recurso.

¿Alguien por favor que pudiera explicar cuál sería la forma correcta de formar el cuerpo del archivo Json?

En esta parte recibo los campos que formarán el cuerpo de Json desde un formulario:

```
public ActionResult Producto(string tit, string cat, int pre, string mon, int can, string mdc, string 
      con, string des, string img)

        {

            var p = new Parameter("access_token", m.AccessToken, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            var ps = new List<Parameter>();
            ps.Add(p);
            var r = m.PostItem("https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?access_token=", new
            {
                title=tit,
                category_id = cat,
                price =pre,
                currency_id = mon,
                available_quantity = can,
                buying_mode = mdc,
                condition = con,
                description = des,
                pictures = img

            });
```

Siempre me devuelve un `Badrequest`:

```
 public IRestResponse PostItem(string resource, object body)
      {
  var request = new RestRequest(resource + AccessToken, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddJsonBody(body);
        var response = ExecuteRequest(request); 

      }
```

Así es como tendría que quedar. Sin embargo el campo `picture` cuenta con `source` y `[{}]` y no sé cómo formar el cuerpo de esa manera:

```
    {
    "title":"Articulo",
    "category_id":"MLM1152",
    "price":330,
    "currency_id":"MXN",
    "available_quantity":10,
    "buying_mode":"llevar",
    "listing_type_id":"bronze",
    "condition":"new",
    "description": "Descripcion ",
    "pictures": 
    [{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ray_Ban_Original_Wayfarer.jpg"}]
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has probado cambiando `pictures = img` por `pictures = new { source = img }`?

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia gracias por la respuesta, no había intentado de esa manera y lo acabo de realizar, se guarda de esta manera  pictures = { source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/.jpg" }  y me sigue arrogando erro  le faltan los corchetes, no se se mucho del tema y intente agregarlos así "[" pero no me funciona.

Comment: El problema es que el pictures es un array y lo estas pasando como si fuera uno solo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tu objeto le falta agregar un array, aunque solo tenga un foto en ese array. Este deberia ser tu clase y en base a eso se crea el objeto.

```
var r = new Producto
            {
                title = "",
                category_id = "",
                price = 3,
                currency_id = "",
                available_quantity = 10,
                buying_mode = "",
                condition = "",
                description = "",
                pictures = new Picture[] { new Picture("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ray_Ban_Original_Wayfarer.jpg")}

            };

public class Producto
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string currency_id { get; set; }
    public int available_quantity { get; set; }
    public string buying_mode { get; set; }
    public string listing_type_id { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Picture[] pictures { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public Picture(string name)
    {
        source = name;
    }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Si la pregunta te soluciono el problema marcala como aceptada, Si tenes otra pregunta, publicala en otra pregunta nueva. para que se entieda bien y borra los comentarios sobre esta respuesta para que quede limpio

Comment: Gracias, me resolvió la pregunta.

Comment: Olvidé la matriz (los `[]`) en mi comentario. Te llevas mi +1